# using gst-launch-1.0 to record audio to an audio file from any pipewiresrc input

Tags: linux, gstreamer, wav, usb-camera

I'm trying to record my camera's audio into an audio file, i tired wav or mp3 with `lame` and `twolame` but the results are the same, so lets stick to wav file for now.

I'm on gentoo linux with kernel 6.7.6-gentoo with hyprland (and wayland)

so running `st-device-monitor-1.0 Audio/Source` shows:

```
Device found:

    name  : HD Pro Webcam C920 Analog Stereo
    class : Audio/Source
    caps  : audio/x-raw, layout=interleaved, format=S16LE, rate=[ 16000, 32000 ], channels=2
    properties:
        alsa.card = 1
        alsa.card_name = HD Pro Webcam C920
        alsa.class = generic
        alsa.device = 0
        alsa.driver_name = snd_usb_audio
        alsa.id = USB Audio
        alsa.long_card_name = HD Pro Webcam C920 at usb-0000:00:14.0-10.2, high speed
        alsa.name = USB Audio
        alsa.resolution_bits = 16
        alsa.subclass = generic-mix
        alsa.subdevice = 0
        alsa.subdevice_name = subdevice #0
        api.alsa.card.longname = HD Pro Webcam C920 at usb-0000:00:14.0-10.2, high speed
        api.alsa.card.name = HD Pro Webcam C920
        api.alsa.path = front:1
        api.alsa.pcm.card = 1
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = capture
        audio.channels = 2
        audio.position = FL,FR
        card.profile.device = 0
        device.api = alsa
        device.class = sound
        device.id = 55
        device.profile.description = Analog Stereo
        device.profile.name = analog-stereo
        device.routes = 1
        factory.name = api.alsa.pcm.source
        media.class = Audio/Source
        node.description = HD Pro Webcam C920 Analog Stereo
        node.name = alsa_input.usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_B71E5BFF-02.analog-stereo
        node.nick = HD Pro Webcam C920
        node.pause-on-idle = false
        object.path = alsa:pcm:1:front:1:capture
        priority.driver = 2009
        priority.session = 2009
        factory.id = 18
        clock.quantum-limit = 8192
        client.id = 32
        node.driver = true
        factory.mode = split
        audio.adapt.follower = 
        library.name = audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert
        object.id = 63
        object.serial = 67
    gst-launch-1.0 pipewiresrc target-object=67 ! ...
```

now.. running `gst-launch-1.0 pipewiresrc target-object=67 ! autoaudiosink` does work, i can hear the sound from my camera

now i'm trying to record it to a wav file (i added debug output):

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=3 pipewiresrc target-object=67 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! wavenc ! filesink location=output.wav
```

I get:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.011095507 110033 0x7fe5e4000b70 FIXME                default gstutils.c:4036:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<pipewiresrc0:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:00.017102534 110033 0x7fe5dc002500 ERROR             video-info video-info.c:540:gst_video_info_from_caps: wrong name 'audio/x-raw', expected video/ or image/
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: pipewireclock0
Redistribute latency...
0:00:00.0 / 99:99:99. <- and it's stuck here
```

this error is weird `video-info video-info.c:540:gst_video_info_from_caps: wrong name 'audio/x-raw', expected video/ or image/` since it's an audio source.

any ideas?

## update

it seems like any device that i choose using pipewire src provides the same error.

even when I use my built in Audio:

```
Device found:

    name  : Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    class : Audio/Source
    caps  : audio/x-raw, layout=interleaved, format={ (string)S32LE, (string)S16LE }, rate=[ 44100, 192000 ], channels=2
    properties:
        alsa.card = 0
        alsa.card_name = HDA Intel PCH
        alsa.class = generic
        alsa.device = 0
        alsa.driver_name = snd_hda_intel
        alsa.id = ALC897 Analog
        alsa.long_card_name = HDA Intel PCH at 0x4406220000 irq 247
        alsa.name = ALC897 Analog
        alsa.resolution_bits = 16
        alsa.subclass = generic-mix
        alsa.subdevice = 0
        alsa.subdevice_name = subdevice #0
        api.alsa.card.longname = HDA Intel PCH at 0x4406220000 irq 247
        api.alsa.card.name = HDA Intel PCH
        api.alsa.path = front:0
        api.alsa.pcm.card = 0
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = capture
        audio.channels = 2
        audio.position = FL,FR
        card.profile.device = 0
        device.api = alsa
        device.class = sound
        device.id = 56
        device.profile.description = Analog Stereo
        device.profile.name = analog-stereo
        device.routes = 3
        factory.name = api.alsa.pcm.source
        media.class = Audio/Source
        node.description = Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
        node.name = alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.3
        node.nick = ALC897 Analog
        node.pause-on-idle = false
        object.path = alsa:pcm:0:front:0:capture
        priority.driver = 2009
        priority.session = 2009
        factory.id = 18
        clock.quantum-limit = 8192
        client.id = 32
        node.driver = true
        factory.mode = split
        audio.adapt.follower = 
        library.name = audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert
        object.id = 91
        object.serial = 1146
    gst-launch-1.0 pipewiresrc target-object=1146 ! ...
```

and when I run

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=3 pipewiresrc target-object=1146 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! wavenc ! filesink location=output.wav
```

i get the same error:

```
0:00:00.033190751 1873059 0x7f1d98002550 ERROR             video-info video-info.c:540:gst_video_info_from_caps: wrong name 'audio/x-raw', expected video/ or image/
```

i'm using gstreamer 1.22.3 with pipewire 1.0.4 on gentoo linux.

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your pipeline on Ubuntu 22.04 with GStreamer 1.20.3, and I'm seeing the exact same behaviour (pipeline gets stuck at `0:00:00.0 / 99:99:99.`)

The exact same pipeline works for me if I replace `pipewiresrc` with either `alsasrc` or `pulsesrc`, and if I throw in an `identity dump=true`, I can see that the buffers produced by Pipewire are noticeably larger than those from ALSA or Pulse. Unfortunately, the `blocksize` parameter for `pipewiresrc` doesn't seem to have an effect for me. Also, if you use `gst-launch-1.0 -tv ...`, you can see the caps used by the individual elements, and Pipewire seems to prefer F32LE/48kHz, while Pulse and ALSA use S16LE/44.1kHz. Forcing the caps doesn't do anything either, though.

So the best workaround I can offer right now would be to simply use `alsasrc` or `pulsesrc` instead of `pipewiresrc`. I would actually assume this is a bug related to not streaming into a live sink.

Comment: thank you for providing more information on how to debug issues in the future, i really appreciate it.